# if statement not running which includes an async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function inside an if/else statement. I just want to check whether there is a file in the request body before even using it otherwise it throws an error. Why is this happening? And is there anything better I could do to handle the problem ?

```
//save image to cloudinary
if (typeof(banner) !== undefined) {
  //this piece of code is always executing even if the image is not present in request or is undefined
  cloudinary.uploader.upload(banner,
    async function(error, result) {

      if (error) {
        return res.status(409).send("Something went wrong while uploading image")
        console.log(error)
      }
      article.banner = result.url
      const savedArticle = await article.save()
      return res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify({
        redirect_uri: "/articles/" + savedArticle.slug
      }))

    })
} else {
  return res.status(400).send("Missing file")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your outer `if` does nothing, because `typeof banner` will never be the value `undefined` (it could be the string `"undefined"` though).

`typeof` returns a **string** with the type name in it, so `if (typeof banner !== 'undefined')` should work.

However, most likely you don't even need `typeof` here - `if (banner !== undefined)` or even just `if (banner)` should work too in your case.